# bluemix, manifest production stage

Tags: database, ibm-cloud

I am trying to make a production stage within bluemix, But I keep on getting errors. I made 2 seperate spaces and added the app and the services. I have binded my production app to another database but still it keeps searching for the database that i use at the development app. I think it is because bluemix is looking in the manifest file does someone knows how to fix this?

[image: error of mystage wich is productionstage]

[image: error is the wie logs]

Comment: Show us the files and the errors

Comment: i have uploaded pictures @data_henrik

Comment: What commands are run, how does the manifest.yml look like?

Comment: I made 2 manifest files 1 for the deploy and 1 for the mystage it is working still getting the wrong database could this be because of db.php file? @data_henrik

Comment: I haven't seen any file. See the comments above

Comment: @data_henrik I solved the issue Thanks!

Comment: In your deploy phase you are able to edit the deployment script manually. You could change the command to:
"cf push -f path_to_manifest.yml"
Which will make sure your deployment phase is grabbing the correct manifest.